# Play Framework - value login is not a member of controllers.Application

Tags: java, playframework

I'm running the latest Play Framework 2.5.1 and I'm getting an error from my log on page:

Error:

```
value login is not a member of controllers.Application
```

I have tried adding the `@` symbol i.e:

```
@controllers.Application.login()
```

And removing the injector from the `build.sbt`, clean up/ clean-files and updates in "CMD". I'm using the sample from https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide.

HTML CODE

```
@(form: Form[Application.Login])
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Zentasks</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/login.css")">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href=@routes.Application.index" id="logo"><span>Zen</span>tasks</a>
        </header>

    </body>
</html>
```

CONTROLLERS

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }



    public static Result login() {
        return ok(
            login.render(form(Login.class))
        );
    }

    public static class Login {
        public String email;
        public String password;
    }   

}
```

ROUTES

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

GET     /login                      controllers.Application.login()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               @controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Comment: Have a look here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/JavaHome at the documentation as your using a 2.1.x tutorial with 2.5.x framework at present.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `static` keyword from your controller's actions. Play 2.5.1 uses dependency injection by default and if you want to use `static` actions, you need to [explicitly configure it](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Routes-generated-with-InjectedRoutesGenerator). So, your login action must be like:

```
// no static keyword here
public Result login() {
    return ok(login.render(form(Login.class)));
}
```

#### Update:

By the way, you are mixing a lot of things here. I recommend you to not follow 2.1.0 guide while developing for version 2.5.x since there is a lot of differences between these two versions. In fact, Play 2.1.0 is from **Feb 06 2013**.

Here are some references that explain why your code was failing:

1. [Java Routing: Dependency Injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRouting#Dependency-Injection)
2. [Dependency injecting controllers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Dependency-injecting-controllers)
3. [Replaced static controllers with dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Replaced-static-controllers-with-dependency-injection)