# Play Framework compile error "type Index is not a member of object controllers.Application" when referring to Java class in controller from view

Tags: java, playframework

I am trying to help out another developer on this, but I cannot seem to fix this issue.  I am compiling a Play application and I continually receive this error:

```
C:\myapp\app\views\index.scala.html:1: type Index is not a member of object controllers.Application
[error] @(indexForm: Form[Application.Index])
```

I have reviewed other applications that I have written, but cannot find a solution for this.

Here is the controller:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public class Index {
        public String name;
        public String title;
    }

public Result index() {
    // Open the index page...
    return ok(index.render(form(Index.class)));
}

...
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@(indexForm: Form[Application.Index])

@main(null) {
    <section id="homePage">
        <div class="container">
            <h3><b>Here is your index page</b></h3>
            <div class="testimonials">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="testim_content">You can customize this as your landing page</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" style="margin: auto;">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="/add$$APPNAME$$" class="buttonCustomView" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Add New " + mainTable + "</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="/view$$APPNAME$$" class="buttonCustomView" style="color: #FFFFFF;">View All " + mainTable + "</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="/login" class="buttonCustomView" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

I have been reviewing this posts:

[Play Framework - value login is not a member of controllers.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345421/play-framework-value-login-is-not-a-member-of-controllers-application)

[Play Framework For Scala: Compilation error[type Application is not a member of package controllers]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543960/play-framework-for-scala-compilation-errortype-application-is-not-a-member-of)

I have tried renaming the classes but still no luck.

I know it is probably an easy answer, but I cannot figure out what it is.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**In controller**

```
... 

@Inject
FormFactory formFactory;

public Result index() {

    Index index = new Index();
    index.set..
    ...

    Form<Index> indexForm = formFactory.render(form(Index.class)));

    return ok(views.html.index.render(indexForm.fill(index)));

}
```

**In view**

```
@(indexForm: play.data.Form[controllers.Application.Index])
```

If no success, move the `Index` class into new package and try with `[package_name.Index]` .